# Can someone explain why this compiles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I am a newbie in Python and was experimenting and just ran the following code:

```
a=13
a==14
print(a)
```

I expected the program not to compile due to the second line although surprisingly it does (although I couldn't see any changes that it made). Can someone explain why? If I use `a===14` instead of `a==14` there's an error.

Comment: The actual code is 
a=13 (new line)
a==14 (new line)
print(a)

Comment: Why wouldn't `==` be valid? In the REPL it would print a Boolean for an equality check. In a script, it still performs the equality check but just discards the result. `=` is an assignment, `==` checks for equality of values

Comment: `a==4` is a valid Python expression. It evaluates to either true or false.

Comment: Thanks roganjosh and khelwood I got ur point

Comment: Because `==` is a comparison operator...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a==14` is not a statement, it's an expression. It produces a boolean result, that is discarded as soon as it is produced. It is a line that has absolutely no effect on the program.

On the other hand, there is no `===` operator in python, that's why your program fails in that case. Contrary to javascript, python is a *strongly typed* language, it does not do implicit conversions. The `==` of python is similar to `===` in javascript.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it *is* a statement. It's an expression statement. See `expr_stmt` in the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html).

Answer (score 0):

a = 13 assign the value 13 to a.

a==14 compare a and 14 and return false because 13 != 14

So a==14 is valid

Answer (score 0):

here
     a=13 will assign value 13 to variable a

a==14 will check whether value of a is 14 or not

a===13 will give error , as there is no operator `===`

insort. `=` operator assign values, `==` compare and `===` there is no such operator